# Question about exception (try-catch) within a loop

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have this problem a few times already on other projects as well. Right now I try to understand exception handling but I still don't know how it exactly works.
I tried to program a calculator with a loop and when I try to input a String, there will be InputMismatchException - I tried to catch it, but for some reason after the catch clause, java gives me another InputMismatchException, why?

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int loop = 1;
        while (loop == 1) {

            try {

                System.out.println("First number:");
                int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Second number:");
                int num2 = scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Choose operator (1 for +)(2 for -)(3 for *)(4 for /): ");

                int userInput = scanner.nextInt();

                switch (userInput) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Result: " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + (num1 + num2));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Result: " + num1 + " - " + num2 + " = " + (num1 - num2));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Result: " + num1 + " * " + num2 + " = " + (num1 * num2));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Result: " + num1 + " / " + num2 + " = " + (num1 / num2));
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input!");

                }

                System.out.println("Repeat? (1 = yes)(0 = nein)");

                loop = scanner.nextInt();

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input, try again!");
                scanner.nextInt();

            }

        }
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println("Ciao!");

    }

}
```

At first there was an infinite loop, which I solve by `scanner.nextInt();` within the catch block, but still I get this error:

```
Choose operator (1 for +)(2 for -)(3 for *)(4 for /): 
er
Invalid Input, try again!
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:47)
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you did not fetch the nextInt, since the next value was not an `int`. thus you try to fetch the same input again in your catch block and thus have a InputMismatchException again.

Your Stacktrace also points to the catch clause where you try to retrieve the next `int`!

I suggest you just replace `nextInt` in the catch clause with `nextLine`:

```
...
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input, try again!");
    scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Then you will start your loop again and try to read anew.

Also checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) similar thread on stackoverflow or the [tutorialspoint examples for using the `Scanner` class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm).

Comment: You are right of cause, so just read and disregard the non-int input by reading the next line and start the loop again adn ask for a new input. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your first case it enters into the infinite loop as `InputMismatchException` is thrown by `scanner.nextInt();` and you have handled that exception so it will again go for next iteration which eventually invokes `scanner.nextInt();` again but in that case, the scanner does not move to the new line, so it will get String instead of int which it was expecting and will throw `InputMismatchException`. You can solve it by :

```
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input, try again!");
            scanner.nextLine(); // change nextInt to nextLine
        }
```

In your current code when InputMismatchException throws it goes to catch block and your catch block and again it execute `scanner.nextInt();` which throw the exception and your loop thread terminate.

Comment: Wow thank you!! But why exactly I have to use `scanner.nextLine()` ?

Comment: nextLine() past the scanner current line

Answer (score 0):

1. After you catch the exception you should scan the mismatch input. You can use `scanner.nextLine()` and the scanner will scan the bad input so your loop starts again.
2. Your program start over after the exception. If you want to continue the loop after the exception you have to use multiple try catch and use do while till the user enter the correct input.

```
Integer num1 = null;
do {
   try {
     num1 = scanner.nextInt();
   } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
     System.out.println("Invalid Input, try again!");
     scanner.nextLine();
   }
} while (num1 == null);
```

Answer (score -1):

if we want to catch the exception rather than throwing it outside the method then line which could potentially throw the exception should be in try block like

```
try{
//code which can throw exception T
}
catch( exceptions T){
// what if exception handle it
}
```

but in your case  scanner.nextInt(); is producing the exception in try block and control goes to catch block here again you executing same line  scanner.nextLine();
which again throw the exception and this time it is not handled 
remove scanner.nextInt(); line from catch block